# Trip to Macau through HKIA Airport

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, hong-kong

I am planning to go from Beijing to Macau from Hong Kong Airport through the ferry terminal.

Indians do not need a visa for Macau but a PAR for entry into Hong Kong.

I am planning my return to India after two days through Hong Kong airport

Will I require any visa or PAR for Hong Kong, if I do not intend to leave the transit area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=hk&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Those who are in direct (Air to Air
>   or Air to Sea) transit if holding confirmed onward bookings,
>   continuing their journey within 48 hours and not leaving the
>   transit lounge.

So no, you do **not** need a visa.